# VS 2010 Coded UI Test Not Finding Window

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

**I couldn't get the SO text editor to mark parts of the post correctly so if you can trick SO into properly formatting the exception text and the code, that would be greatly appreciated.**

Context:

- VS 2010 Premium
- Windows 7 Professional 32-bit edition
- VB .Net WinForms app named "Testing Testing"
- MSTest test project named "TestProject1" with a file named "CodedUITest1.vb"
- First created "CodedUITest1.vb" as part of the tutorial at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/11/05.

I took an existing coded UI test ("CodedUITest1.vb") and recorded an additional test using the test recorder provided by VS 2010.

I also followed instructions from another SO post to make the "Testing Testing" executable launch and close as part of test initialization and cleanup respectively.

However, now, when I run my unit tests, 2 instances of "Testing Testing.exe" launch and then I get the following exception:

```
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
  BasicMessage=The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.
  HResult=-268111872
  Message=The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
ControlType:  'Window'
Name:  'Debug'
ClassName:  'CabinetWClass'
```

CodedUITest1.vb:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'  <auto-generated>
'      This code was generated by coded UI test builder.
'      Version: 10.0.0.0
'
'      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'      the code is regenerated.
'  </auto-generated>
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Imports System
Imports System.CodeDom.Compiler
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Windows.Input
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
Imports Keyboard = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Keyboard
Imports Mouse = Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse
Imports MouseButtons = System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons

Namespace TestProject1

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Partial Public Class UIMap

        '''<summary>
        '''TestAdd - Use 'TestAddParams' to pass parameters into this method.
        '''</summary>
        Public Sub TestAdd()
            Dim uIDesktopList As WinList = Me.UIProgramManagerWindow.UIFolderViewWindow.UIDesktopList
            Dim uIItem7Button As WinButton = Me.UICalculatorWindow.UIItem7Window.UIItem7Button
            Dim uIItemButton As WinButton = Me.UICalculatorWindow.UIItemWindow.UIItemButton
            Dim uIItem2Button As WinButton = Me.UICalculatorWindow.UIItem2Window.UIItem2Button
            Dim uIItemButton1 As WinButton = Me.UICalculatorWindow.UIItemWindow1.UIItemButton

            'Click 'Desktop' list box
            Mouse.Click(uIDesktopList, New Point(51, 491))

            'Launch '%windir%\System32\calc.exe'
            Dim uICalculatorWindow As ApplicationUnderTest = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(Me.TestAddParams.UICalculatorWindowExePath, Me.TestAddParams.UICalculatorWindowAlternateExePath)

            'Click '7' button
            Mouse.Click(uIItem7Button, New Point(6, 14))

            'Click '+' button
            Mouse.Click(uIItemButton, New Point(16, 14))

            'Click '2' button
            Mouse.Click(uIItem2Button, New Point(13, 11))

            'Click '=' button
            Mouse.Click(uIItemButton1, New Point(11, 27))
        End Sub

        '''<summary>
        '''AssertSum - Use 'AssertSumExpectedValues' to pass parameters into this method.
        '''</summary>
        Public Sub AssertSum()
            Dim uIItem9Text As WinText = Me.UICalculatorWindow.UIItem9Window.UIItem9Text

            'Verify that '9' label's property 'DisplayText' equals '9'
            Assert.AreEqual(Me.AssertSumExpectedValues.UIItem9TextDisplayText, uIItem9Text.DisplayText)
        End Sub

        '''<summary>
        '''JustTyping - Use 'JustTypingParams' to pass parameters into this method.
        '''</summary>
        Public Sub JustTyping()
            Dim uITypeEdit As WinEdit = Me.UIDebugWindow.UIItemWindow.UITestingTestingexeListItem.UITypeEdit
            Dim uITextBox1Edit As WinEdit = Me.UIForm1Window.UITextBox1Window.UITextBox1Edit

            'Click 'Type' text box
            Mouse.Click(uITypeEdit, New Point(66, 6))

            'Type 'test' in 'TextBox1' text box
            uITextBox1Edit.Text = Me.JustTypingParams.UITextBox1EditText
        End Sub

        '''<summary>
        '''CheckingTheTextbox - Use 'CheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues' to pass parameters into this method.
        '''</summary>
        Public Sub CheckingTheTextbox()
            Dim uITextBox1Edit As WinEdit = Me.UIForm1Window.UITextBox1Window.UITextBox1Edit

            'Verify that 'TextBox1' text box's property 'Text' equals 'test'
            Assert.AreEqual(Me.CheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues.UITextBox1EditText, uITextBox1Edit.Text)
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property TestAddParams() As TestAddParams
            Get
                If (Me.mTestAddParams Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mTestAddParams = New TestAddParams()
                End If
                Return Me.mTestAddParams
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property AssertSumExpectedValues() As AssertSumExpectedValues
            Get
                If (Me.mAssertSumExpectedValues Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mAssertSumExpectedValues = New AssertSumExpectedValues()
                End If
                Return Me.mAssertSumExpectedValues
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property JustTypingParams() As JustTypingParams
            Get
                If (Me.mJustTypingParams Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mJustTypingParams = New JustTypingParams()
                End If
                Return Me.mJustTypingParams
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Overridable ReadOnly Property CheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues() As CheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues
            Get
                If (Me.mCheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mCheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues = New CheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues()
                End If
                Return Me.mCheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property UIProgramManagerWindow() As UIProgramManagerWindow
            Get
                If (Me.mUIProgramManagerWindow Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIProgramManagerWindow = New UIProgramManagerWindow()
                End If
                Return Me.mUIProgramManagerWindow
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property UICalculatorWindow() As UICalculatorWindow
            Get
                If (Me.mUICalculatorWindow Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUICalculatorWindow = New UICalculatorWindow()
                End If
                Return Me.mUICalculatorWindow
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property UIDebugWindow() As UIDebugWindow
            Get
                If (Me.mUIDebugWindow Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIDebugWindow = New UIDebugWindow()
                End If
                Return Me.mUIDebugWindow
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property UIForm1Window() As UIForm1Window
            Get
                If (Me.mUIForm1Window Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIForm1Window = New UIForm1Window()
                End If
                Return Me.mUIForm1Window
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mTestAddParams As TestAddParams

        Private mAssertSumExpectedValues As AssertSumExpectedValues

        Private mJustTypingParams As JustTypingParams

        Private mCheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues As CheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues

        Private mUIProgramManagerWindow As UIProgramManagerWindow

        Private mUICalculatorWindow As UICalculatorWindow

        Private mUIDebugWindow As UIDebugWindow

        Private mUIForm1Window As UIForm1Window
        #End Region
    End Class

    '''<summary>
    '''Parameters to be passed into 'TestAdd'
    '''</summary>
    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class TestAddParams

        #Region "Fields"
        '''<summary>
        '''Launch '%windir%\System32\calc.exe'
        '''</summary>
        Public UICalculatorWindowExePath As String = "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"

        '''<summary>
        '''Launch '%windir%\System32\calc.exe'
        '''</summary>
        Public UICalculatorWindowAlternateExePath As String = "%windir%\System32\calc.exe"
        #End Region
    End Class

    '''<summary>
    '''Parameters to be passed into 'AssertSum'
    '''</summary>
    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class AssertSumExpectedValues

        #Region "Fields"
        '''<summary>
        '''Verify that '9' label's property 'DisplayText' equals '9'
        '''</summary>
        Public UIItem9TextDisplayText As String = "9"
        #End Region
    End Class

    '''<summary>
    '''Parameters to be passed into 'JustTyping'
    '''</summary>
    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class JustTypingParams

        #Region "Fields"
        '''<summary>
        '''Type 'test' in 'TextBox1' text box
        '''</summary>
        Public UITextBox1EditText As String = "test"
        #End Region
    End Class

    '''<summary>
    '''Parameters to be passed into 'CheckingTheTextbox'
    '''</summary>
    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class CheckingTheTextboxExpectedValues

        #Region "Fields"
        '''<summary>
        '''Verify that 'TextBox1' text box's property 'Text' equals 'test'
        '''</summary>
        Public UITextBox1EditText As String = "test"
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIProgramManagerWindow
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name) = "Program Manager"
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName) = "Progman"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Program Manager")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIFolderViewWindow() As UIFolderViewWindow
            Get
                If (Me.mUIFolderViewWindow Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIFolderViewWindow = New UIFolderViewWindow(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUIFolderViewWindow
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIFolderViewWindow As UIFolderViewWindow
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIFolderViewWindow
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId) = "1"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Program Manager")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIDesktopList() As WinList
            Get
                If (Me.mUIDesktopList Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIDesktopList = New WinList(Me)
                    Me.mUIDesktopList.SearchProperties(WinList.PropertyNames.Name) = "Desktop"
                    Me.mUIDesktopList.WindowTitles.Add("Program Manager")
                End If
                Return Me.mUIDesktopList
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIDesktopList As WinList
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UICalculatorWindow
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name) = "Calculator"
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName) = "CalcFrame"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIItem7Window() As UIItem7Window
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItem7Window Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItem7Window = New UIItem7Window(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItem7Window
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property UIItemWindow() As UIItemWindow
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItemWindow Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItemWindow = New UIItemWindow(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItemWindow
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property UIItem2Window() As UIItem2Window
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItem2Window Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItem2Window = New UIItem2Window(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItem2Window
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property UIItemWindow1() As UIItemWindow1
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItemWindow1 Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItemWindow1 = New UIItemWindow1(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItemWindow1
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property UIItem9Window() As UIItem9Window
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItem9Window Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItem9Window = New UIItem9Window(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItem9Window
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIItem7Window As UIItem7Window

        Private mUIItemWindow As UIItemWindow

        Private mUIItem2Window As UIItem2Window

        Private mUIItemWindow1 As UIItemWindow1

        Private mUIItem9Window As UIItem9Window
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIItem7Window
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId) = "137"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIItem7Button() As WinButton
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItem7Button Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItem7Button = New WinButton(Me)
                    Me.mUIItem7Button.SearchProperties(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name) = "7"
                    Me.mUIItem7Button.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItem7Button
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIItem7Button As WinButton
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIItemWindow
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId) = "93"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIItemButton() As WinButton
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItemButton Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItemButton = New WinButton(Me)
                    Me.mUIItemButton.SearchProperties(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name) = "Add"
                    Me.mUIItemButton.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItemButton
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIItemButton As WinButton
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIItem2Window
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId) = "132"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIItem2Button() As WinButton
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItem2Button Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItem2Button = New WinButton(Me)
                    Me.mUIItem2Button.SearchProperties(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name) = "2"
                    Me.mUIItem2Button.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItem2Button
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIItem2Button As WinButton
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIItemWindow1
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId) = "121"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIItemButton() As WinButton
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItemButton Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItemButton = New WinButton(Me)
                    Me.mUIItemButton.SearchProperties(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name) = "Equals"
                    Me.mUIItemButton.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItemButton
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIItemButton As WinButton
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIItem9Window
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlId) = "150"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIItem9Text() As WinText
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItem9Text Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItem9Text = New WinText(Me)
                    Me.mUIItem9Text.SearchProperties(WinText.PropertyNames.Name) = "Result"
                    Me.mUIItem9Text.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItem9Text
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIItem9Text As WinText
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIDebugWindow
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name) = "Debug"
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName) = "CabinetWClass"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Debug")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UIItemWindow() As UIItemWindow2
            Get
                If (Me.mUIItemWindow Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUIItemWindow = New UIItemWindow2(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUIItemWindow
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUIItemWindow As UIItemWindow2
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIItemWindow2
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.AccessibleName) = "Items View"
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName) = "DirectUIHWND"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Debug")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UITestingTestingexeListItem() As UITestingTestingexeListItem
            Get
                If (Me.mUITestingTestingexeListItem Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUITestingTestingexeListItem = New UITestingTestingexeListItem(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUITestingTestingexeListItem
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUITestingTestingexeListItem As UITestingTestingexeListItem
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UITestingTestingexeListItem
        Inherits WinListItem

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinListItem.PropertyNames.Name) = "Testing Testing.exe"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Debug")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UITypeEdit() As WinEdit
            Get
                If (Me.mUITypeEdit Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUITypeEdit = New WinEdit(Me)
                    Me.mUITypeEdit.SearchProperties(WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name) = "Type"
                    Me.mUITypeEdit.WindowTitles.Add("Debug")
                End If
                Return Me.mUITypeEdit
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUITypeEdit As WinEdit
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UIForm1Window
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name) = "Form1"
            Me.SearchProperties.Add(New PropertyExpression(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName, "WindowsForms10.Window", PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains))
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Form1")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UITextBox1Window() As UITextBox1Window
            Get
                If (Me.mUITextBox1Window Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUITextBox1Window = New UITextBox1Window(Me)
                End If
                Return Me.mUITextBox1Window
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUITextBox1Window As UITextBox1Window
        #End Region
    End Class

    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
    Public Class UITextBox1Window
        Inherits WinWindow

        Public Sub New(ByVal searchLimitContainer As UITestControl)
            MyBase.New(searchLimitContainer)
            Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName) = "TextBox1"
            Me.WindowTitles.Add("Form1")
        End Sub

        #Region "Properties"
        Public ReadOnly Property UITextBox1Edit() As WinEdit
            Get
                If (Me.mUITextBox1Edit Is Nothing) Then
                    Me.mUITextBox1Edit = New WinEdit(Me)
                    Me.mUITextBox1Edit.WindowTitles.Add("Form1")
                End If
                Return Me.mUITextBox1Edit
            End Get
        End Property
        #End Region

        #Region "Fields"
        Private mUITextBox1Edit As WinEdit
        #End Region
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Helpful suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <GeneratedCode("Coded UITest Builder", "10.0.30319.1")>  _
Public Class UICalculatorWindow
    Inherits WinWindow

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New
        Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name) = "Calculator"
        Me.SearchProperties(WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName) = "CalcFrame"
        Me.WindowTitles.Add("Calculator")
    End Sub
```

If you look at the last line of the constructor, it adds a string to the WindowTitles list. This string is the name of the window that was selected when you made the action recording.

You'll run into a problem if the WindowsTitle has changed, because the program uses that string to determine which window to perform an action in. So if your window title has changed, say from "Calculator" to "Program Manager", you will have to make sure you change the WindowTitle appropriately. Example:

```
Me.UICalculatorWindow.WindowTitles.Clear();
Me.UICalculatorWindow.WindowTitles.Add("type new window title here");
```

This way when your coded ui test is trying to perform an action, like a click on a link, it knows which window to look for the link in.